# Django-autocomplete-url invalid URL

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to be able to autocomplete from a list of Institution. I think I have included everything I needed from the django-autocomplete-light tutotial but I am getting this error and not sure what is causing it.  Hope you can help.

The error is:

```
URL lookup for autocomplete 'InstitutionAutocomplete' failed. Have you included autocomplete_light.urls in your urls.py?
```

My django-autocomplete-light folder is on the same level as my app. There was another thread about putting it in the wrong directory, but it seems all files can be imported properly.  Not sure how to test this though.

Here is my urls.py:

```
import autocomplete_light
autocomplete_light.autodiscover()
admin.autodiscover()

url(r'^profile/add_user_accounts$', UserAccountsUpdate.as_view(), name='add_user_accounts'),
url(r'^profile/autocomplete$', include('autocomplete_light.urls'), name='autocomplete'),
```

Here is my auto_complete_light.py in my app/ directory:

```
import autocomplete_light
from models import Institution

class InstitutionAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    search_fields = ['^name', ]
    attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Find your institution',
        'data-autocomplete-minimum-characters': 1,
    }

autocomplete_light.register(Institution, InstitutionAutocomplete)
```

My form is:

```
class AddUserAccountsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for adding new user financial accounts.

    """
    required_css_class = 'required'
    user_institution_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=Institution.objects.all(), widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('InstitutionAutocomplete'))
    user_accounts_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'User Name'}), label="")
    user_accounts_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}), label="")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_institution_name','user_accounts_name', 'user_accounts_password', )
```

My Html is:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<form action="" method="get" role="form">
    <input id="InstitutionsSearch" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search for your institution" autocomplete="off">
</form> 

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have terminated your including URL with "$", so nothing after that can match. Change it to:

```
url(r'^profile/autocomplete', ...)
```

without the $.

Note that the most recent versions of Django raise a warning when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your `urls.py` file, try changing this:

```
url(r'^profile/autocomplete$', include('autocomplete_light.urls'), name='autocomplete')
```

to this:

```
url(r'^profile/autocomplete$', include('autocomplete_light.urls', name='autocomplete'))
```

It might need to be `namespace` instead of `name`, I'm not certain.

Comment: I removed the name just to check, but I get the same error.